# How to know the Exact reason code crash from my crash report in Xcode

Tags: xcode, crash, sigabrt

The following is the crash report which is observed at the time of launching.

http://pastie.org/9713653

Comment: look at your drawTextInRect method, most cases its usually due to not calling the super method.

Comment: i am not using any such method in project

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report in order to find out which line the crash occurred.

Comment: @trojanfoe How to Symbolicate crash report

Comment: Do a search to find out.

Comment: @trojanfoe i came to know we need to have taht Ipa to symbolicate. in my crash report versiion number is missing. how to know which version it belongs too?

Comment: I don't think you can.  The report is useless.

Comment: Y.i got this report from my friend iphone                   Identifier: AppName 
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2014-11-12 06:24:28.692 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.6 (10B500)
Report Version:  104